# Rules on castling, what is allowed

Tags: rules, castling

I have learned about a move called castling, where you move the castle and the king to switch. Can anybody explain the rules? Thanks.

Comment: This is very similar to the following question: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/80/is-castling-possible-if-any-of-the-squares-involved-in-the-castling-are-under-at?rq=1

Comment: @Ed Dean: I agree that it is basically a duplicate.

Answer (score 10):

Castling is done by moving the King two squares towards the Rook, and then placing the Rook on the square that the King skipped over. In order to castle, all of the following must be true.

- It's your turn.
- The squares between your King and your Rook are all unoccupied.
- You have not yet moved your King.
- You have not yet moved the Rook that you are using to castle.
- You are not currently in check.
- You will not end up in check.
- The square that your King passes through must not be under attack by an enemy piece (in other words, your King will not pass through check).